# Zoom further in than level 19 with leaflet javascript API?

Tags: leaflet, zoom

We're using the leaflet JavaScript API with a tile layer which supports zoom level up to 19.  I'd like users to be able to zoom further even if the tiles blur as they have to place markers to a high degree of accuracy.

Is this possible ?

We want the map to zoom not the markers or other elements.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do it now, as of version 0.7 there is an additional option called 'maxNativeZoom' after which it will interpolate tiles.

Here's a [link to the latest documentation for `maxNativeZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#gridlayer-maxnativezoom)

Here's the info:

```
minZoom Number  0   Minimum zoom number.
maxZoom Number  18  Maximum zoom number.
maxNativeZoom   Number  null    Maximum zoom number the tiles source has available. If it is specified, the tiles on all zoom levels higher than maxNativeZoom will be loaded from maxZoom level and auto-scaled.
```

A code example that I use to achieve it is here:

```
var aerial = new L.tileLayer(serverURL + "/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/Orthophoto/ImageServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}", {
    attribution: attribution,
    maxZoom: 20,
    maxNativeZoom: 18
});
```

Comment: perfect solution